# the program itself runs but all dialogs created are not called

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I tried creating a few dialogs for a program.. thing is when executed. nothing happens, so I tried the basic hello world getInput code below:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()


name = droid.dialogCreateInput("Hello!", "What's your Name?")
print name
droid.makeToast("Hello, %s" % name.result)
```

lf
thing is when I view the name *Which is essentially the result of the dialogCreateInput* nothing happens, it's as if the dialog isn't called and a dialogShow would not work using the name variable. if I use the droid variable as below:

```
droid.dialogShow()
```

with the code above. it'll say that there is no dialog to show. so i do not know what I can do to call any dialogs for use in programming. some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `droid.dialogGetInput` if you want a result from a single call. It's a convenience, so you don't need to use the `dialogCreateInput`, `dialogShow` and `dialogGetResponse` methods for just getting input. There's a `dialogGetPassword` method that does the same thing. In all other cases you need to do at least three calls to do a dialog. Try these [docs](http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/); they're a little bit more explanatory.